# Using Regex from command line to extract number

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I am using a tool to calculate cylomatic complexity of a javascript file.

Example:

```
jsc --minimal test.js
```

This command will give the following output.

```
┌─────────────────────┬─────┬────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ File                │ LOC │ Cyclomatic │ Halstead difficulty │
├─────────────────────┼─────┼────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ /home/shray/test.js │ 23  │ 4          │ 10                  │
└─────────────────────┴─────┴────────────┴─────────────────────┘
Cyclomatic: min 4 mean 4.0 max 4
Halstead: min 10 mean 10.0 max 10
```

Now I use

```
jsc --minimal test.js | grep "Cyclomatic:"
```

which gives me output as

```
Cyclomatic: min 4 mean 4.0 max 4
```

Now I have a regex, `Cyclomatic:[\s]*min[\s]+([0-9]+)` but I am not able to use it to extract the number showing minimum Cylomatic value.

Any help how can I just ouput the value of Min or Max Cyclomatic complexity value on the terminal output?

Comment: `Cyclomatic: min 4 mean 4.0 max 4` this structure will always remain same? Just the values will change?

Comment: "_I am not able to use it_" how did you try and what happened? Do you have GNU `grep` (are you using Linux or UNIX)?

Comment: I don't know how to use this regex in terminal to extract the value. I tried using the regex with grep but it did not output anything then. I am using Ubuntu16  @roima

Comment: Yes the structure remains same @Pacifist

Comment: `...|awk '/Cyclomatic/ {print $3,$7}'` can you try this then ? It will give you min and max numbers only for Cyclomatic.

Comment: It gives correct output if I use ` $jsc --minimal test.js | grep Cyclomatic: |  awk '/Cyclomatic/ {print $3,$7}`
But adds two vertical bars above the numbers if I do not use grep first. Thanks a lot @Pacifist

Comment: @Shray `...|awk '/Cyclomatic:/ {print $3}' ` can you try this one then?

Comment: Yep works awesome. Thanks @Pacifist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that this line is always of the same format, you can use a simple `cut`:

```bsh
cut -d' ' -f3
```

or with `awk` you can do the whole thing including your first `grep`:

```bsh
awk '$1 == "Cyclomatic:" {print $3}'
```

If the line might change, use `sed`:

```bsh
sed -E 's/.*( min )([0-9]+).*/\2/'
```

or `grep -P` if available:

```bsh
grep -Po ' min \K[0-9]+'
```

or normal `grep`:

```bsh
grep -o 'min [0-9]\+'
```

This returns `min 4`, which you can easily filter adding another `grep` or `cut`

```bsh
grep -o '[0-9]\+$'
# or
cut -d' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, using a look-behind (`-P` is only in Gnu grep):

```
jsc --minimal test.js | grep -Po '(?<=Cyclomatic: min )\d+'
```

(this extracts the first group of digits that follows `"Cyclomatic: min "`).